# Condition DropDown Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, dropdown

i have a database with 9 Country Location row and each has 0 and 1 value for Country enable and disable for service, and i want that enabled country (Which hold Value 1) in the dropdown 
like this

```
$options = array(

if(($row->s_loc_london)==1)
{
    'location_lond' => 'London',
}

form_dropdown('service_location', $options, $row->s_type );
```

Comment: If any answers below helped you don't for get to accept them

Answer (score 1):

Please find below solution with example.

Codeigniter `form_builder` has inbuilt function to generate dropdown from dynamic array of key/value pair array.

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> form_dropdown([$name = ''[, $options = array()[, $selected = array()[, $extra = '']]]]);
> ```

```
$options = array(
        'small'         => 'Small Shirt',
        'med'           => 'Medium Shirt',
        'large'         => 'Large Shirt',
        'xlarge'        => 'Extra Large Shirt',
);

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');
```

> **echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');**

```
Would produce:

<select name="shirts">
        <option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
        <option value="med">Medium  Shirt</option>
        <option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
        <option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

> **echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, $shirts_on_sale);**

```
Would produce:

<select name="shirts" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="small" selected="selected">Small Shirt</option>
        <option value="med">Medium  Shirt</option>
        <option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
        <option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

> **Your Solution**

```
$options = array(
    'london' => 'London',
    'india' => 'India'
);

if ($row->s_loc_london == 1)
{
    $selected_location = 'london';
}

form_dropdown('service_location', $options, $selected_location );
```

Let me know if it not works.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<select name="outlet" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Outlet</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($getOutlet as $outlet)
    {
        $selected = '';
        if(!empty($this->input->get('outlet')))
        {
            if($outlet->id == $this->input->get('outlet'))
            {
                $selected = 'selected';
            }
        }
    ?>
    <option <?=$selected?> value="<?=$outlet->id?>"><?=$outlet->name?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```